# C++ Function templates for only types that extend the same superclass

Tags: templates, c++11

I come from a C# background, where I would be able to do something like this

```
void AddComponent<T>() where T : Component, new()
{
    T newT = new T();
    //Do other things...
    ListOfComponents.Add(newT);
}
```

I'm rather new when it comes to C++ Templates, but after visiting a number of tutorials and sites, I haven't been able understand how to replicate this.

Does anyone know if this is possible in C++ using templates?

Comment: `template <typename T> void AddComponent() { ListOfComponents.Add(new T()); }` `AddComponent<U>` will simply fail to instantiate if `U` cannot be created with `new`, or is not derived from `Component` (assuming `Add` takes `Component*`). If it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck, then it's good enough to be treated as a duck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the `where` is necessary in C# to tell the compiler that `T` can be created with `new` and can be added to the collection. Without that information, the function wouldn't compile.

In C++ you don't need to tell the compiler that information, just write the code you want to write, and if the type can be created with `new` and added to the collection, it will compile without problems. If it can't be created with `new` or can't be added to the collection, it won't compile. You don't need to tell the compiler anything about the type.

So just write something like:

```
template<typename T>
  void AddComponent()
  {
    T newT = new T();
    //Do other things...
    ListOfComponents.insert(newT);
  }
```

(Note that "creating with `new`" means something very different in C++, possibly what you really care about is whether it can be constructed with zero arguments).

The reason this works is that a C++ template is not just a function that operates on generic `Object` types and has some extra information telling it the objects can be cast to more specific types. A C++ template really is a "template" from which a concrete function is generated (kind of like C# reification, but different). If you instantiate a function template with `int` as the template parameter it generates a new function, which is distinct from the function generated by instantiating the template with `float`. So if you instantiate `AddComponent<int>()` the compiler generates a function equivalent to:

```
  void AddComponent()
  {
    int newT = new int();
    //Do other things...
    ListOfComponents.insert(newT);
  }
```

If that compiles then it compiles. You don't need to tell the compiler anything about `int` *because it already knows whether you can use an `int` in that way*. If you can't do those things with an `int` then it doesn't compile. C++ templates are *much* smarter than the limited "generics" in C# and Java, which are basically just operating on `Object` with some implicit casting inserted by the compiler, and so you need to provide constraints to tell the compiler what casting to do. (This is partly because C++ templates are not checked by the compiler until you instantiate them, so you can write a template that is full of errors, and only find out later when you try to use it by instantiating it. C# checks the definition of generics early to ensure they only use properties that are known to work because of the constraints).

Now, you *can* constrain a function template so it won't even *try* to compile if a template argument type doesn't meet certain requirements e.g.

```
template<typename T,
         typename Requires = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value>>
  void AddComponent()
  {
    T newT = new T();
    //Do other things...
    ListOfComponents.insert(newT);
  }
```

This constraints the function template so it can only be called with types that have `Component` as a base class. You could also add a constraint using `std::is_default_constructible<T>`.

However this isn't necessary unless you want to overload `AddComponent` and have another function that does something different if the argument doesn't derive from `Component` (and/or isn't default constructible).

With the "Concepts" feature of C++, which is not yet part of the standard but is defined by an ISO Technical Specification and supported in GCC, you can do:

```
template<typename T>
  void AddComponent() requires std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value
  {
    T newT = new T();
    //Do other things...
    ListOfComponents.insert(newT);
  }
```

But again, this isn't necessary just to make the function compile, only if you want to have multiple overloads of `AddComponent` that do different things depending on the type they are instantiated with.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the in depth overview. Also for writing it in a fashion a person like me can understand.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [type_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits). You may narrow template application only to particular classes or class families using [std::enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).